# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error When transmitting Audio

Tags: java, audio, outputstream

Okay, so i am trying to make a voice chat program with java, and have been unsuccessful so far, because i keep getting this error:**java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error**.

I have both classes for server and client(meaning it's only possible with 2 people), which makes the code same for sending and receiving audio:

Server:

```
    static AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100,16,1,true,false);
    static TargetDataLine microphone;
    static SourceDataLine speakers;
    int errorcounter=0;
    byte[] targetData;
    public void AudioPreparation()
    {
        try{
            DataLine.Info targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
            microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
            speakers = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);
            speakers.open(format);
            microphone.open(format);
            microphone.start();
            speakers.start();
            targetData = new byte[16];
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            errorcounter++;
            if(errorcounter==5)
                System.exit(0);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"Error!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    final static int PORT = 6990;
    PrintWriter textout = null;
    BufferedReader textin = null;
    //DataOutputStream audioOut = null;
    OutputStream audioOut;
    //DataInputStream audioIn = null;
    InputStream audioIn;
    Thread RA = null;
    public void prepare()
    {
        AudioPreparation();

        while(true)
        {
            try {
                ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
                Socket sock = listener.accept();
                textin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                textout = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
                audioOut = sock.getOutputStream();
                audioIn = sock.getInputStream();
                //audioOut = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                //audioIn = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());                
                RA = new Thread(ReceiveAudio);
                break;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        while (true)
        {
            String name;
            try{
                textout.println("SUBMITNAME");
                name = textin.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return;
            }

            if(name==null) 
                return;
            else
            {
                Object[] question = {"Yes","Nope"};
                int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Accept call from: "+name,"Incoming Call!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,question,question[1]);
                if (n==1)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    textout.println("NAMEACCEPTED");
                    statuslabel.setText("Talk Session Active!");
                    RA.start();

                    while(true)
                    {
                        SendAudio();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    int numBytesRead;
    public void SendAudio()
    {
        numBytesRead = -1;
        try{
            numBytesRead = microphone.read(targetData, 0, targetData.length);
            if(numBytesRead>=0)
            {
                //speakers.write(targetData, 0, numBytesRead);
                audioOut.write(targetData, 0, targetData.length);    
                numBytesRead=-1;
                audioOut.flush();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            errorcounter++;
            if(errorcounter==5)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"Error!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            numBytesRead = -1;
        }
    }

    Runnable ReceiveAudio = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            int bytesRead;
            while(true)
            {
                bytesRead = 0;
                try{
                    bytesRead = audioIn.read(targetData, 0, bytesRead);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"Error!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    errorcounter++;
                    if(errorcounter==5)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                if(bytesRead >= 0)
                {
                    speakers.write(targetData, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead=0;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Client:

```
static AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100,16,2,true,false);
static TargetDataLine microphone;
static SourceDataLine speakers;
int errorcounter=0;
public void AudioPreparation()
{
    try{

        DataLine.Info targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
        speakers = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);
        speakers.open(format);
        microphone.open(format);
        microphone.start();
        speakers.start();
        targetData = new byte[16];
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        errorcounter++;
        if(errorcounter==5)
            System.exit(0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"Error!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
public static final int PORT = 6990;
Socket socket;
PrintWriter textout;
BufferedReader textin;
//DataOutputStream audioOut = null;
OutputStream audioOut;
//DataInputStream audioIn = null;
InputStream audioIn;
boolean connection = false;
byte[] targetData;
Thread RA;
public void connect()
{
    while(true)
    {
        String serverAddress = "localhost";
        try {
            socket = new Socket(serverAddress, PORT);
            textin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            textout = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            audioOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            audioIn = socket.getInputStream();
            //audioOut = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            //audioIn = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());     
            RA = new Thread(ReceiveAudio);
            break;
        }catch(IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"Error!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
    }
    while (true) {
        try
        {
            String line = textin.readLine();
            if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                textout.println(getName());
            }else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
                statuslabel.setText("Talk Session Active!");
                RA.start();
                int numBytesRead;
                while(true)
                {
                    numBytesRead = -1;
                    try{
                        numBytesRead = microphone.read(targetData, 0, targetData.length);
                        if(numBytesRead>=0)
                        {
                            audioOut.write(targetData, 0, numBytesRead);    
                            numBytesRead=-1;
                            audioOut.flush();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        errorcounter++;
                        if(errorcounter==5)
                        {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"Error!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        numBytesRead = -1;
                    }
                }

            }
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            errorcounter++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"Error!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            if(errorcounter==5)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
public String getServerAddress() {
    String ipaddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter IP Address of the Server:","Chatter",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    return ipaddress;
}
Runnable ReceiveAudio = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            try{
                bytesRead = audioIn.read(targetData, 0, bytesRead);
            } catch (Exception e){
                bytesRead = 0;
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"Error!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                errorcounter++;
                if(errorcounter==5)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            if(bytesRead > 0)
            {
                speakers.write(targetData, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead=0;
            }
        }
    }
};

String username = "";
public String getName() {
    while("".equals(username))
    {
        username =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Choose a Username:","CryptoTalk",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    return username;
}
```

I have tried transmitting the sound with both DataOutputStream and OutputStream, and i keep getting the same error for both client and server:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
```

This happens exactly when the sending takes place...
I have googled that error, hoping that i will fix this, but have been less than fortunate.
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"Connection reset by peer" generally means that the remote system closed the connection that you tried to write to.  This is not an issue with the type of stream objects you are using; rather, it's a matter of what you do with them.  I'm not sure what that might be, because you have not presented a complete program.

Particularly notable by its absence is the client side of the code for establishing a connection.  I note, too, that the server (listening) side creates a new `Thread` around the `ReceiveAudio` object, but strangely doesn't start it.  Note: variable names should start with lowercase letters: `receiveAudo`.

In any event, it is not helpful to use `DataInputStream` / `DataOutputStream` for this job, as these are targeted at transferring Java primitives and Objects.  Your data are raw as far as Java is concerned.  The stream implementations you obtain from the sockets will do everything you need to do.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your input.
Secondly, i did start the receiveAudio thread, right after textout.println("NAMEACCEPTED").
Thirdly, could you elaborate as to the command that you're reffering to as "The stream implementations you obtain from the sockets"?